# Can I manipulate v-mask in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have an input tag that used v-mask for formattig mobile number:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phoneNumber" class="form-control"  
 v-model="numberAndCaptcha.phoneNumber" @keyup="onNumberChange" v-mask="mask"/>

mask:['###-###-####'] //declared as a data attribute
```

This works fine and number gets formatted as expected

However, on reload I will be pre-populating the input with a number I get from the backend.
The condition is that I have to mask the first six digits of the populated number i.e input will contain number like "********7890**"

But due to v-mask, the resulting value for input has only the last 4 digits of the pre-populated number as v-mask does not accept anything other than digits

Is there any way to get the desired result on reload? i.e number that is masked and also compatible with v-mask?

Answer (score 0):

The mask library works with patterns, and the `#` sign you're using is a pattern that only accepts numbers.

Check out: (from: https://github.com/vuejs-tips/vue-the-mask/blob/master/src/tokens.js)

```
export default {
  '#': { pattern: /\d/ },
  X: { pattern: /[0-9a-zA-Z]/ },
  S: { pattern: /[a-zA-Z]/ },
  A: { pattern: /[a-zA-Z]/, transform: v => v.toLocaleUpperCase() },
  a: { pattern: /[a-zA-Z]/, transform: v => v.toLocaleLowerCase() },
  '!': { escape: true }
}
```

As you can see here, there are different patterns. From have you can extract:

```
#: numbers only
X: numbers and upper/lower letters
S: letters (in which case they are entered)
A: letters (make it uppercase even if it is lowercase)
a: letters (make it lowercase even if it is uppercase)
```